# Composer error when deploy Symfony 3 with Capistrano

Tags: symfony, composer-php, capistrano

I am using Capasitrano to Deploy my Symfony3 Apps.
I have a problem when start to deploy.

this is the result when i running "cap production deploy"

```
00:42 composer:run
      01 composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader
      01 The disk hosting /root/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception
      01
      01
      01   [RuntimeException]
      01   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
      01   Fatal error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /home/cititex/public_h…
      01   In AppKernel.php line 31:
      01
      01     Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bund
      01     le\GeneratorBundle".
      01     Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
      01
      01
      01
      01 install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autolo…
      01
```

so the error is start from "The disk hosting /root/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception"

i have check my disk usage, but still have many memory.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        35G   19G   14G  57% /
devtmpfs        911M     0  911M   0% /dev
tmpfs           920M  4.0K  920M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           920M  8.6M  912M   1% /run
tmpfs           920M     0  920M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      1.3G  2.8M  1.2G   1% /tmp
```

Please help me to find out the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The /root/ directory may be on another partition, which you may not be showing. Doing a `du -skc /root/*` should show where all the space is being taken up - it could well be a large number of cached files (`/root/.composer/cache/`), downloaded by Composer. You can safely remove them with `composer clearcache` (the worst that would happen is that they are downloaded again).

Running composer install as root is usually not a good idea anyway. Better to create a normal, or specific 'deploy' user to run all the tasks. You might need root/sudo access to setup permissions (with setfacl), but probably not even that.

Comment: here is the result we i run du -skc
[root@vps ~]# du -skc
33868   .
33868   total

is it full?

Answer (score 0):

to get your free space in your composer home directory try run `df -h /root/.composer` and run `composer clear-cache` to remove composer cache in composer home directory then run `composer diagnose` to check your system.

Comment: the result for df -h /root/.composer
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        35G   19G   14G  58% /

i fugure out this problem by add set :composer_working_dir, -> { '/home/***/www/***/***' } to deploy.rb

but the error now is : Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 573571072) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/R… Do you have any idea? i have up the memory_limit to 2GB but still not working